# Is there an alternative way to convert points from the axial to the projected plane in VB6?

Tags: geometry, transformation, plane

(Please note that I have also posted this to the Visual Basic 6 Programming list on Yahoo! Groups but that seems to have been dead since 2017 so I thought I would post here as well.)

I've recently taken over maintaining a VB6 program at work that has a routine to convert data points from an axial plane to the projected plane given the axial point, a lead measurement, projection angle, vector (initial angle, final angle, gradient)  and the projected point. It is written as a function that returns a Boolean to indicate whether it was successful.

It has to calculate the rotation angle from the axial plane to do this and uses the Newton-Raphson iteration method to determine the value of this angle. It sets an upper limit of 30 iterations in which to do this, but for a certain set of parameters, it's unable to find a solution within those 30 iterations.

Does anyone know of an alternative method to perform this conversion please? This program is used to drive a CNC machine with the data points calculated and I believe that these parameters are valid it's just the method used that's preventing it from proceeding.

I have added logging output code to trace the problem and found that it is down to a conversion between the axial and projected planes with a specific upper value for the projection angle (it also uses +/- a margin on this value as part of the process).

The iteration code cannot find a solution that falls within the set tolerance within the set maximum number of tries (30).

I have tried increasing the maximum number of tries, reducing the increments, increasing the tolerance and also reducing the value of the margin applied, but none of what I have done so far works, or it duplicates the same error.

I expect the output to be an array of profile points that are on the projected plane and equivalent to the provided axial plane points using the provided lead measurement and projection angle but I am getting errors that indicate the iteration process failed to find a solution within the maximum number of 30 tries.

**Edited to add:**

I've written the following pseudocode based on the VB6 code to try and explain how the routine works:

```
    'AxialPoint, ProjectedPoint: structures with ProfileRadius, ProfileWidth, 
    'NormalAngle, UnwrapAngle and Attribute fields
    'Lead: lead measurement
    'ProjectionAngle: projection angle onto the projected plane in degrees
    'Vector(): provides initial value of Beta, Last Beta value found, Last 
    'gradient) - set by the calling routine as (0, 0, 0) in this case
    'Beta is the angle of rotation from the axial plane
    Function AxialToProjected(AxialPoint, Lead, ProjectionAngle, Vector(), 
    ProjectedPoint):
        LeadAngle := Atn(Lead / (2 * PI * AxialPoint.ProfileRadius)) 'radians
        SA := Sin(LeadAngle)
        CA = Cos(LeadAngle)
        CT := -CosD(AxialPoint.NormalAngle)
        ST := SinD(AxialPoint.NormalAngle)
        SG := SinD(ProjectionAngle)
        CG := CosD(ProjectionAngle)
        C1 := SA * CG * CT
        C2 := CA * CG * ST
        C3 := CA * SG * CT
        Iteration := 0
        FBeta := 0.0001
        While (Abs(FBeta) >= 0.0001) And (Iteration < 9) Do
            NewValue(Beta, OldBeta, FBeta, Increment:=0.1, Gradient, SVB(), 
                Iteration, Multiplier:=10)
            SB := Sin(Beta)
            CB := Cos(Beta)
            OldFBeta := FBeta
            FBeta := C1 * CB + C2 * SB - C3
            If Iteration >= 2 Then
              Gradient := (Beta - OldBeta) / (FBeta - OldFBeta)
            End If
        End While
        If (Abs(FBeta) > 0.0001) Then
            'The code reaches this point with the specific parameters
            Report "Iteration failed to find a solution within 30 tries" error
        Else
            'The code doesn't reach this point
            X3 := Beta * Lead / 2 * PI + AxialPoint.ProfileWidth
            With ProjectedPoint Do
                .ProfileWidth := X3 * CG - AxialPoint.ProfileRadius * SB * SG
                .ProfileRadius := AxialPoint.ProfileRadius * CB
                .NormalAngle := ATan2(CA * CB * CG * ST - SA * SB * CG * CT, 
                    -CA * CT) * RadToDeg
                .Attribute := AxialPoint.Attribute
                .UnwrapAngle := AxialPoint.UnwrapAngle
            End With
        End If
    End AxialToProjected()
```

SinD() and CosD() accept an angle in degrees and convert it to radians before passing that to the normal Sin() and Cos() functions.

The NewValue() routine calculates a new value for Beta from the value of OldBeta using FBeta, Increment, Gradient, SVB() and the Multiplier while incrementing the value of Iteration:

```
    'Beta: current axial plane rotation angle estimate
    'OldBeta: previous current axial plane rotation angle estimate
    'FBeta: gradient of tangent to the normal
    'Increment: increment size to adjust Beta by
    'Gradient: gradient for the Newton method
    NewValue(Beta, OldBeta, FBeta, Increment, Gradient, SVB(), Iteration, 
    Multiplier):
        If Iteration > 2 Then
            MaxChange := Abs(Increment * Multiplier)
            Change := -FBeta * Gradient
            If Abs(Change) > MaxChange Then
                Beta := Beta + TransferSign(MaxChange, Change)
                'TransferSign() will return -MaxChange if Change < 0 or
                'MaxChange if Change >= 0
            Else
                Beta := Beta + Change
            End If
        ElseIf Iteration = 2 Then
            If SVB(3) = 0 Then
                Beta := SVB(1) + Increment
            Else
                Beta := -FBeta * SVB(3)
            End If
        Else
            Beta := SVB(1)  'Set Beta to initial value
        End If
    End NewValue()
```

I'll get a diagram uploaded later as I need to work out how best to draw it from my scribblings :)

Just to add some extra context, the routine is being used to calculate points to machine ZA and ZN type worms using a CNC machine.

It's just 1 specific set of parameters for each type that cause the error to occur and I believe that it's being caused by the initial estimate being too far away from the root to be resolved within the 30 try limit but I'm not sure how to work out a better initial estimate.

**Edited to add:**

Apologies for not returning to the thread sooner as I've been looking into this issue from other angles, but I have managed to put together a simple diagram showing how these planes are related so I hope this helps:

[Coordinate Planes](https://i.stack.imgur.com/VQmp5.png)

When I was looking into the calculation of FBeta in the code, I found something useful in my internet searches based on Pythagoras' Theorem:

1. |C3| \le \sqrt{C1^2+C2^2} - the Newton iteration loop will be able to find a solution
2. |C3| > \sqrt{C1^2+C2^2} - the Newton iteration loop will not be able to find a solution

I've modified the code to perform this check at the start and only enter the Newton loop if equation (1) holds true, otherwise, it currently reports an error, but I'd like to find an alternative method to find a solution.

Comment: Welcome to SO! It would be very very and very good if you add some draws (with given data and nomenclature) and the code that fails. Best a [mcr example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/reprex). Newton-Raphson may get confused when the solution is maximum or a minimum.

Comment: Hi Ripi2 - not a problem, I was being mindful that I don't post anything proprietary, but the math is all related to geometry so is all public domain stuff anyway. I'll edit my original post to add some more information.

Comment: Honestly, I do not know what you mean by "axial plane, axial point and projected plane" unless you give me some geometric context: e.g. "I have a plane somewhere in space, positioned so and so in my coordinate system, and a point, somewhere in the coordinate system, not lying on the plane and another plane, positioned so and so in the coordinate system...." And if, alongside a direct geometric explanation, you post a drawing, it is likely you will get an answer.